# How to have the Civi Contact deleted when the Drupal User is cancelled?

Tags: contacts, user-account

When a user cancels his registration in Drupal, the pertaining Civi Contact remains.

How can I have both deleted simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module if you have the [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module installed.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your suggestion ; I have just installed those Modules (together with Entity_Token and Entity API (prerequisites)) ; what next ? (I am not a programmer).

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, wouldn't want the contact deleted. Maybe tag or group them differently but I'd want the history that is contained within the contact record.

Comment: When the user wants to be deleted, I assume both in Drupal and CiviCM ; and how can he tag or group his Civi record (from Drupal) ?

Comment: @Jacques-MarieMoranne Deleting both Drupal and CiviCRM records may be appropriate in your situtation. However, if you have contribution data recorded against the CiviCRM contact record then for financial audit purposes it may no be feasible to delete the CiviCRM record.